# How can I access multiple class variables from the same package?

Tags: java, class, package

I've been trying to write a GUI for testing a JDBC connection that uses a JComboBox to select the drive like MySQL or PostgreSQL. There are also multiple JTextFields to insert host, port, database, username, etc, so I can use it in my future projects.

[GUI for test JDBC connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HG1T.png)
I have a class for the GUI part and other classes for actions, but the button that test the connection needs to access to the `JComboBox` and all the `JTextField`s to try the `Connection`.
I made `protected static` my variables so I can access from the main gui class but I think is a bad idea and I WANT MY CODE AS MUCH EASY TO READ AND EASY TO RE-WRITE in the future.

Here's the main GUI class.

```
public Class JDBCManager extends JPanel {
    protected static JButton jButtonTest;
    protected static ArrayList<String[]> arrayListDrivers;
    protected static JComboBox jComboBoxDriver;
    protected static JTextField jTextFieldHost;
    protected static JTextField jTextFieldPort;
    protected static JTextField jTextFieldDatabase;
    protected static JTextField jTextFieldUsername;
    protected static JPasswordField jPasswordFieldPassword;
    protected static JTextField jTextFieldURL;
    public JProgressBar jProgressBar;
    protected static JButton jButtonOK;
    protected static JButton jButtonCancel;

/**
 * Initializes all the components in the GUI.
 */
public JDBCManager() {
    // Local variables
    JLabel jLabelDriver = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabelHost = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabelPort = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabelDatabase = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabelUsername = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabelPassword = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabelURL = new JLabel();
    arrayListDrivers = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    jComboBoxDriver = new JComboBox();
    jTextFieldHost = new JTextField();
    jTextFieldPort = new JTextField();
    jTextFieldDatabase = new JTextField();
    jTextFieldUsername = new JTextField();
    jPasswordFieldPassword = new JPasswordField();
    jTextFieldURL = new JTextField();
    jProgressBar = new JProgressBar();
    jButtonTest = new JButton();
    jButtonOK = new JButton();
    jButtonCancel = new JButton();

    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("internationalization/JDBCManager/Messages", Locale.getDefault());

    // Get default font
    Font font = UIManager.getDefaults().getFont("Label.font");

    jLabelDriver.setText(resourceBundle.getString("DRIVER NAME:"));
    jLabelDriver.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

    jLabelHost.setText(resourceBundle.getString("HOST:"));
    jLabelHost.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

    jLabelPort.setText(resourceBundle.getString("PORT:"));
    jLabelPort.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

    jLabelDatabase.setText(resourceBundle.getString("DATABASE NAME:"));
    jLabelDatabase.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

    jLabelUsername.setText(resourceBundle.getString("USERNAME:"));
    jLabelUsername.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

    jLabelPassword.setText(resourceBundle.getString("PASSWORD:"));
    jLabelPassword.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

    jLabelURL.setText(resourceBundle.getString("DATABASE URL:"));
    jLabelURL.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

    jComboBoxDriver.addActionListener(new DatabaseDriver());

    JTextComponent[] jTextComponents = new JTextComponent[] {
        jTextFieldHost,
        jTextFieldPort,
        jTextFieldDatabase,
        jTextFieldURL,
        jTextFieldUsername};
    JComponent[] jComponents = new JComponent[] {jButtonTest, jButtonOK};
    TextComponentInputVerifier textComponentImputVerifier = new TextComponentInputVerifier(jTextComponents, jComponents);

    jTextFieldHost.addCaretListener(new DatabaseURLVerifier());
    jTextFieldHost.addCaretListener(textComponentImputVerifier);
    jTextFieldHost.setTransferHandler(null);
    jTextFieldHost.setColumns(30);

    jTextFieldPort.addCaretListener(new DatabaseURLVerifier());
    jTextFieldPort.addCaretListener(textComponentImputVerifier);
    jTextFieldPort.addKeyListener(new TextDataInputVerifier(TextDataInputVerifier.NUMERICAL));
    jTextFieldPort.addKeyListener(new TextLengthInputVerifier(5));
    jTextFieldPort.addKeyListener(new TextNumberRangeInputVerifier(1, 65535));
    jTextFieldPort.setTransferHandler(null);
    jTextFieldPort.setColumns(30);

    jTextFieldDatabase.addCaretListener(new DatabaseURLVerifier());
    jTextFieldDatabase.addCaretListener(textComponentImputVerifier);
    jTextFieldDatabase.setTransferHandler(null);
    jTextFieldDatabase.setColumns(30);

    jTextFieldUsername.addCaretListener(textComponentImputVerifier);
    jTextFieldUsername.setTransferHandler(null);
    jTextFieldUsername.setColumns(30);

    jPasswordFieldPassword.addCaretListener(textComponentImputVerifier);
    jPasswordFieldPassword.setTransferHandler(null);
    jPasswordFieldPassword.setColumns(30);

    jTextFieldURL.addCaretListener(textComponentImputVerifier);
    jTextFieldURL.setTransferHandler(null);
    jTextFieldURL.setColumns(30);

    jProgressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    jProgressBar.setString("");
    jProgressBar.setFont(new Font(font.getName(), Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 16));

    jButtonTest.setText(resourceBundle.getString("TEST DATABASE CONNECTION"));
    jButtonTest.addActionListener(new DatabaseAction());

    jButtonOK.setText(resourceBundle.getString("OK"));

    jButtonCancel.setText(resourceBundle.getString("CANCEL"));

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    jPanel.add(jLabelDriver, gbc);
    jPanel.add(jComboBoxDriver, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    jPanel.add(jLabelHost, gbc);
    jPanel.add(jTextFieldHost, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    jPanel.add(jLabelPort, gbc);
    jPanel.add(jTextFieldPort, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    jPanel.add(jLabelDatabase, gbc);
    jPanel.add(jTextFieldDatabase, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    jPanel.add(jLabelUsername, gbc);
    jPanel.add(jTextFieldUsername, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    jPanel.add(jLabelPassword, gbc);
    jPanel.add(jPasswordFieldPassword, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 6;
    jPanel.add(jLabelURL, gbc);
    jPanel.add(jTextFieldURL, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 7;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    jPanel.add(jButtonTest, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 8;
    jPanel.add(jProgressBar, gbc);

    JPanel jPanelButtons = new JPanel();
    jPanelButtons.add(jButtonOK);
    jPanelButtons.add(jButtonCancel);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(jPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jPanelButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

}
```

And here is my `ActionListener` class.

```
public final class DatabaseTestConnection extends Thread {

/**
 * Sets the current thread priority minor to the normal priority to not interfere
 * with other threads with normal priority and then starts the current thread.
 */
protected DatabaseTestConnection() {
    setPriority(NORM_PRIORITY - 1);
    start();
}

/**
 * Performs the run of this current thread in order to control different GUI
 * components when the testing database connection button is pressed.
 * 
 * <p>
 * When the database testing operation ends, those components are
 * restored to it's previous state.
 * </p>
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("internationalization/DatabaseTestConnection/Messages", Locale.getDefault());

    // Get all the caret listeners from the text components
    CaretListener[] caretListenerHost = JDBCManager.jTextFieldHost.getCaretListeners();
    CaretListener[] caretListenerPort = JDBCManager.jTextFieldPort.getCaretListeners();
    CaretListener[] caretListenerDatabase = JDBCManager.jTextFieldDatabase.getCaretListeners();
    CaretListener[] caretListenerUsername = JDBCManager.jTextFieldUsername.getCaretListeners();
    CaretListener[] caretListenerPassword = JDBCManager.jPasswordFieldPassword.getCaretListeners();
    CaretListener[] caretListenerURL = JDBCManager.jTextFieldURL.getCaretListeners();

    // Remove all the caret listeners for each text component
    // to prevent user selection of text field and enable the
    // buttons while testing the database connection
    // Add all the caret listeners for each text component
    removeAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jTextFieldHost, caretListenerHost);
    removeAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jTextFieldPort, caretListenerPort);
    removeAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jTextFieldDatabase, caretListenerDatabase);
    removeAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jTextFieldUsername, caretListenerUsername);
    removeAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jPasswordFieldPassword, caretListenerPassword);
    removeAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jTextFieldURL, caretListenerURL);

    JDBCManager.jComboBoxDriver.setEnabled(false);
    JDBCManager.jTextFieldHost.setEnabled(false);
    JDBCManager.jTextFieldPort.setEnabled(false);
    JDBCManager.jTextFieldDatabase.setEnabled(false);
    JDBCManager.jTextFieldUsername.setEnabled(false);
    JDBCManager.jPasswordFieldPassword.setEnabled(false);
    JDBCManager.jTextFieldURL.setEnabled(false);
    JDBCManager.jButtonTest.setEnabled(false);
    JDBCManager.jButtonOK.setEnabled(false);
    JDBCManager.jButtonCancel.setEnabled(false);

    JDBCManager.jProgressBar.setString(resourceBundle.getString("TESTING DATABASE CONNECTION..."));
    JDBCManager.jProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

    String url = JDBCManager.jTextFieldURL.getText();
    String username = JDBCManager.jTextFieldUsername.getText();
    String password = DigestPassword.digestPassword(JDBCManager.jPasswordFieldPassword.getPassword());

    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseTestConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DatabaseTestConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null,
                resourceBundle.getString("THE CONNECTION TO THE DATABASE IS ESTABLISHED!"),
                "JDBC Manager",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null,
                resourceBundle.getString("THE CONNECTION TO THE DATABASE COULD NOT BE ESTABLISHED!"),
                "JDBC Manager",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }

    // Add all the caret listeners for each text component
    addAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jTextFieldHost, caretListenerHost);
    addAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jTextFieldPort, caretListenerPort);
    addAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jTextFieldDatabase, caretListenerDatabase);
    addAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jTextFieldUsername, caretListenerUsername);
    addAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jPasswordFieldPassword, caretListenerPassword);
    addAllCaretListeners(JDBCManager.jTextFieldURL, caretListenerURL);

    // Enable all the components
    JDBCManager.jComboBoxDriver.setEnabled(true);
    JDBCManager.jTextFieldHost.setEnabled(true);
    JDBCManager.jTextFieldPort.setEnabled(true);
    JDBCManager.jTextFieldDatabase.setEnabled(true);
    JDBCManager.jTextFieldUsername.setEnabled(true);
    JDBCManager.jPasswordFieldPassword.setEnabled(true);
    JDBCManager.jTextFieldURL.setEnabled(true);
    JDBCManager.jButtonTest.setEnabled(true);
    JDBCManager.jButtonOK.setEnabled(true);
    JDBCManager.jButtonCancel.setEnabled(true);

    JDBCManager.jProgressBar.setString("");
    JDBCManager.jProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
}

/**
 * Adds each event listener contained in a {@code CaretListener[]}
 * to the {@code JTextComponent} specified both in the method parameters.
 * 
 * @param jTextComponent the {@code JTextComponent} to add the events
 * contained in the {@code CaretListener[]}.
 * @param caretListener the {@code CaretListener[]} with the events
 * to add to the {@code JTextComponent}.
 */
private void addAllCaretListeners(JTextComponent jTextComponent, CaretListener[] caretListener) {
    for (int i = 0; i < caretListener.length; i++)
        jTextComponent.addCaretListener(caretListener[i]);
}

/**
 * Removes each event listener contained in a {@code CaretListener[]}
 * from the {@code JTextComponent} specified both in the method parameters.
 * 
 * @param jTextComponent the {@code JTextComponent} to remove the events
 * contained in the {@code CaretListener[]}.
 * @param caretListener the {@code CaretListener[]} with the events
 * to remove from the {@code JTextComponent}.
 */
private void removeAllCaretListeners(JTextComponent jTextComponent, CaretListener[] caretListener) {
    for (int i = 0; i < caretListener.length; i++)
        jTextComponent.removeCaretListener(caretListener[i]);
    }
}
```

So, as I said before, I want to know the best way to access all of my variables from the same package and get the code easy to read and modify by other programmers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `but I think is a bad idea` ... and I would agree.  It violates "Separation of concerns".  DatabaseTestConnection should not know anything about who calls it, whether it's a GUI or whatever.  The job of DatabaseTestConnection is to test the database connection, NOT to perform gui operations.  One option for example, is that the caller provides an object that includes all the parameters (not J-whatever fields, just the values) together with a result member that DatabaseTestConnection can set to indicate success/failure.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Great idea about providing just the values. I'll will try.